# how does this game load its modules?

Tags: javascript, module

[This](http://playbiolab.com/biolab.js) game uses `ig.module('impact.font').requires('impact.image')`  for impact/font.js
but when i see source code via Google Developer Tools i dont see `<script>` for `impact/font.js` (in http://playbiolab.com page) Why? how do they load them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code is in biolab.js. The 'modules' aren't external files (at least not by the time the code is delivered to the browser).

Comment: in that case, why use  ig.module('...').requires('...')??

Comment: Presumably because they use separate files during development, but also for separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are defined at http://playbiolab.com/biolab.js. Instead of starting with the developer tools, you can also view the source of the page, then search for `<script` (without closing `>`).

If you cannot understand the code, because it's packed, use http://jsbeautifier.org.